# Деплой Django-проекта на pythonanywhere + Ru-Center

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Хотел развернуть django-проект на коротком url.

Купил домен на Ru-Center. Сам проект я задеплоил на pythonanywhere.

Как теперь можно сменить url сайта, на купленный с Ru-Center?

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на [официальную документацию](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/OwnDomains/) PythonAnywhere касательно этого вопроса.

К слову,

> If you have a paid account on PythonAnywhere, you can set up web apps on your own domain -- that is, a domain that is not your-username.pythonanywhere.com

то есть вам нужен платный аккаунт на PythonAnywhere, чтобы провернуть такой трюк.